# Docker container cannot resolve the subdomain defined in local machine

Tags: php, docker, nginx, subdomain, resolve

I have defined a subdomain on my local server and I want to request to subdomain from docker container but the container can not resolve the subdomain. **local server uses nginx and is not a docker container**.

Local nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /data/www/html/sites/car/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name car.localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Local server hosts - /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       car.localhost
```

Curl error in docker container

```
echo shell_exec("curl http://car.localhost 2>&1");
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: [0] cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: car.localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers have their own hosts file and do not care what you have in your host's `/etc/hosts`.

If you want the container to have extra hosts you can pass that as an argument  to the docker run see here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts

Or in docker-compose file see here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts

Moreover depending on the network - the container's `127.0.0.1` might not point to the host machine. If you're using `host` network then it should work. But if you're using a bridge or the default config then it will be different. In this case you can use `docker.internal` on MAC/PC or `host.docker.internal` with the spceial `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` on linux.

Comment: using  --network=host in docker command solved my problem. thx.